# Does square of differential of argument is the same as differential of differential of square of argument?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential

Well, I have a problem: if x is an independent argument so is 
$$dx^2 = (dx)^2$$
?
Or if $z = z(x, y)$ is $dz^2 = (dz)^2$?
If not, why? I really can't understand it.

Comment: By the chain rule,$$d(x^2)=2xdx$$

Comment: If you speak about the notation, $dx^n $ quite often is used meaning $(dx)^n $.

Comment: just a difference in notation?